# ¿Es correcto mencionar texto entre rayas y luego hacer referencia a él desde el texto principal?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En una crónica de un periódico leo lo siguiente:

> Como establece la ley, los acusados —nueve en prisión preventiva y tres en libertad bajo fianza— tuvieron un turno final para pronunciar las últimas palabras. Los primeros disponían de quince minutos y los segundos, de cinco.
>
> <sub>[Los acusados se despiden poniendo deberes a los jueces](https://www.eldiario.es/politica/juicio-proces-Cuixart-Sanchez_0_909209865.html), Íñigo Sáenz de Ugarte en eldiario.es, 12 junio 2016</sub>

Como vemos, el autor desglosa el término *los acusados* indicando, entre rayas, que son nueve de un tipo y tres de otro. Posteriormente, utiliza este desglose para indicar que *los primeros tal y los segundos, cual*.

Según recuerdo de mis clases de lengua, todo texto contenido entre comas o entre paréntesis es un texto *secundario*, que se lee pero cuyo contenido es prescindible y queda "encapsulado". Por ello, podemos decir:

> Mis amigos, que tengo muchos, son muy majos.

Y quitar la parte entre comas para dejar el mismo significado:

> Mis amigos son muy majos.

Siguiendo con este hilo argumental, y suponiéndolo cierto y también aplicado al texto entre rayas, ¿es correcto que el autor describa información entre guiones para luego lo "desencapsule" y lo trate en el texto principal?

Comment: Curioso, no sé si es correcto pero en realidad no me ha sonado mal. El objetivo es que se entienda lo que se quiere transmitir, y este texto lo consigue. Vale que el texto entre guiones sea un inciso, un texto secundario, pero forma parte del texto a fin de cuentas, no puedes obviar que está ahí. Por tanto, como texto que ya se ha mencionado, no veo que sea un error referenciarlo más adelante. Pero esto es una opinión personal, va a tocar someterlo a más altas instancias.

Comment: No sé decir si se puede hacer eso o no pero según el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=kyRrDVgsOD6Xup8Dpt) el inciso de las rayas tiene un aislamiento menor que los paréntesis, lo que no sé que supone eso en la práctica: *«Los incisos entre rayas suponen un aislamiento mayor con respecto al texto en el que se insertan que los que se escriben entre comas, pero menor que los que se escriben entre paréntesis»*

Comment: @blonfu eso suena a que si vas a hacer un inciso dentro de un inciso dentro de un inciso, el orden de precedencia sería "paréntesis, guiones, comas". Pero vamos, si tienes que hacer tantos incisos anidados es que estás escribiendo "Las mil y una noches" cuanto menos.

Comment: @Charlie no creo que se refiera a eso que se menciona también en esa entrada. Un inciso se puede hacer con comas, con rayas o con paréntesis y cada uno de ellos tiene su grado de aislamiento, así lo he entendido yo

Comment: @blonfu caramba, interesante. Por tanto, la jerarquía sería que la coma es el menor aislamiento, luego iría la raya y finalmente el paréntesis. Mi profesor de lengua (allá por 4.º de la ESO...) nos dio esta regla (lo dicho entre comas no se utiliza después) refiriéndose a la coma, por lo que siguiendo lo dicho por el DPD también debería aplicar a la raya y el paréntesis.

Comment: Por cierto, en tu pregunta hablas de *guiones* pero son *rayas* en realidad: *Este signo ortográfico (-) no debe confundirse con la raya (—).*

Comment: @blonfu mmm sí, si bien el autor en eldiario.es utilizó guiones y no rayas.

Comment: @walen Yo me refería a que para el caso de la pregunta se usa la raya, no el guion. Otra cosa es que por limitaciones del teclado o por lo que sea no se utilice el signo correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que la frase puede llegar a entenderse, sí que es cierto que la redacción queda un tanto extraña al estar los elementos referenciados dentro de un inciso. Si se elimina el inciso, "los primeros" haría referencia a "los acusados", y "los segundos" daría un `NullReferenceException`.

Por el poder que me habéis otorgado, he consultado a la RAE a través de Enclave, siendo esta su respuesta:

> En efecto, no parece posible recuperar del contexto la referencia de *los primeros* y de *los segundos*, tanto por el significado de estos ordinales y de los cardinales *nueve* y *tres* como por el sintagma nominal *los acusados* que está fuera del inciso.

A continuación sugieren dos formas alternativas de redacción y puntuación que eliminan este problema:

> Como establece la ley, los acusados —nueve en prisión preventiva y tres en libertad bajo fianza— tuvieron un turno final para pronunciar las últimas palabras. Los que estaban en prisión preventiva disponían de quince minutos, y los demás/otros, de cinco.
>
> Como establece la ley, los acusados tuvieron un turno final para pronunciar las últimas palabras. Los nueve que estaban en prisión preventiva disponían de quince minutos, y los tres en libertad bajo fianza, de cinco.

Debo decir que el segundo ejemplo coincide con la redacción alternativa que pensé cuando leí la pregunta, y que me parece que queda bastante compacta y clara.

Comment: Me encanta el léxico que usan: _no parece posible recuperar del contexto_. Realmente hace pensar en variables globales y locales, siendo el texto entre rayas algo local.

Comment: @fedorqui por eso mismo se me vino a la cabeza la idea de que "los primeros" y "los segundos" eran punteros, no he podido evitarlo. :-D